# How to set isKeyboardFocusable = true?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, automation

I'm trying to automate the sign-in process of a WPF Application. I used UISpy to get the properties below.

I'm unable to call Focus() and SetFocus() on the AutomationElement. It throws the error "Target element cannot receive focus"

How can I change the isKeyboardFocusable property to true or how can I get around this?

```
AutomationElement
  General Accessibility
    AccessKey:  ""
    AcceleratorKey: ""
    IsKeyboardFocusable:    "False"
    LabeledBy:  "(null)"
    HelpText:   ""

  State
    IsEnabled:  "True"
    HasKeyboardFocus:   "False"

  Identification
    ClassName:  ""
    ControlType:    "ControlType.Edit"
    Culture:    "(null)"
    AutomationId:   ""
    LocalizedControlType:   "edit"
    Name:   ""
    ProcessId:  "15656 (iexplore)"
    RuntimeId:  "42 10487454 2 3 1 0"
    IsPassword: "False"
    IsControlElement:   "True"
    IsContentElement:   "True"

  Visibility
    BoundingRectangle:  "(1155, 363, 212, 20)"
    ClickablePoint: "(null)"
    IsOffscreen:    "False"

ControlPatterns
  Value
    Value:  ""
    IsReadOnly: "False"
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.